# Join between fact and dimension using comparison operator

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, data-warehouse

I have a fact table with `datestart` and `enddate` and other columns. There is another dimension having `lowerdate` and `upperdate` columns and others.

We have a requirement to join these two tables like this:

```
select somecolumnsfromfactanddimension
from fact f
inner join dimension d
   on f.startdate <= d.upperdate
      and f.enddate >= d.lowerdate
```

`fact` is having 70K records and `dimension` is having 11K records, but this whole query returns close to 600 millions records.

Can someone please explain to me in which scenario does this join make sense and how to best handle such joins.

Comment: The query you have posted is not legal syntax, so it's hard to guess.  If you put a comma after the "fact f", then you are getting a cross join and that could be one explanation of why you are seeing more rows than you expect.  Please post a more complete repro with some sample data.